# Converting a double (the primitive type) to an enumerated type in Java

Tags: java, enums, token, tokenize

I'm trying to convert a String, which represents a function (eg: f(x) = 2.5x + 10) to an ArrayList of tokens. This is what I have for tokens:

```
public enum Tokens
{
    add,
    sub,
    mul,
    div,
    pow,
    exp,
    sin,
    cos,
    tan,
    sec,
    csc,
    cot,
    log,
    x,
    sta,
    end;
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is basically cast a double to a "Tokens" type while preserving the value of the double so that constants can be represented in the same way for later processing, but I don't know how to accomplish this.

Comment: Enums are finite values. You can not create an Enum representing every possible double value. But you can certainly encapsulate a value in other kinds of objects.

Comment: Why don't you make a `Token` type whose fields include a (possibly null) `Double` and a (possibly null) `TokenEnum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're discovering, your `Tokens` enum can't really be used for the actual tokens, because there's no way of making different versions of a `Tokens.x` (I'm guessing `Tokens.x` was meant to represent a number in a formula...) to hold different number values.

What you need is a `Token` class--a "real" class--which can hold (at least) a token type and a value:

```
public class Token {
    private TokenType type;
    private Object value;
    public Token(TokenType type) { 
        this.type = type; 
        this.value = null;
    }
    public Token(TokenType type, Object value) { 
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }
    // getters and setters for type and value omitted below
    // ...
}
```

`TokenType` would be an enum; the `value` attribute is an `Object` so it can hold any type of value object you might need for different token types.

Now, there are a couple of ways to go when deciding how to use the `type` and `value` attributes to represent your tokens.

One way would be rename your current `Tokens` enum to `TokenType` and use its values for your types.  Most token types, such as `TokenType.csc` and `TokenType.add`, wouldn't need any value at all because the `type` tells you everything you need to know.  But number tokens need to know their associated numeric value, so they would  have a `type` of `TokenType.x` and the `value` would hold the numeric value as a `Double`, `Integer`, `BigDecimal`, or whatever.

However, you'll probably find it more convenient to have token types that represent broader syntactic categories, such as "binary operator", "unary operator", "number", "end-of-formula":

```
public enum TokenType {BINOP, UNOP, NUMBER, END};
```

BINOP and UNOP tokens would use the `value` attribute to indicate specific operator they represent.  Enums are perfect for this purpose:

```
public enum BinOps {ADD, SUB, MUL, ... };
public enum UnOps {SIN, COS, TAN, ... };
```

NUMBERs would carry their numeric value in the `value` attribute (again, as `Double`, `Integer`, `BigDecimal`, or whatever).  END tokens wouldn't need any `value`.

Comment: Alternatively, it might be useful to have the `Tokens` enumeration implement an interface, and also have other classes that implement the same interface but hold data (such as, say, a `Number` class that holds a number, or an `Identifier` class that holds a string like "x").

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question. But if you want to convert enum to double, you can do like this.

```
public enum Tokens{
  add(2.0);

  private double value;
  Tokens(double value){
    this.value = value; 
  }

  public double getValue(){
    return this.value;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Tokens.add.getValue());
    double a = 2.0;
    for (Tokens token:Tokens.values()) {
        if(a == token.getValue()){
            System.out.println(token);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I try adding this, Eclipse says `The constructor Tokens() is undefined`.

Comment: Add main method. It runs.